# When The RPC Server is unavailable How Can I Pass It?

Tags: c#, methods, network-programming, wmi

Here is my codes. I am trying to get computer information on network and I have two methods to get them. But when the machine is not online I got this Error. How can I pass these machine when they are not online.

```
public string GetBoardSerNo(string machineName)
    {
        string y = "";

        try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new
                ManagementObjectSearcher("\\\\" + machineName + "\\root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard");

            foreach (ManagementObject wmi in searcher.Get())
            {

                return wmi.GetPropertyValue("SerialNumber").ToString();


            }
        }
        finally
        {
            y = "Serial Number: Unknown";

        }

        return y;

    }
    public string GetModel(string machineName)
    {
        string x = "";

        try
        {

            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new
                ManagementObjectSearcher("\\\\" + machineName + "\\root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");

            foreach (ManagementObject wmi in searcher.Get())
            {
                return wmi.GetPropertyValue("Model").ToString();

            }

        }
        finally
        {
            x = "Model No: Unknown";

        }
        return x;

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *" How can I pass"* ?

Comment: [link](http://i.hizliresim.com/0bXmDY.png) I got this error and It s still trying to get information. I want to make it go on for another machines.

Comment: How about `catch`ing the exception?

Comment: I think you mean `catch` instead of `finally`.

Comment: when I use catch it is still not entering catch block It s just giving   this error. How can I share all solution with you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself. Thanks for your help.

```
    {

        try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new
                ManagementObjectSearcher("\\\\" + machineName + "\\root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard");

            foreach (ManagementObject wmi in searcher.Get())
            {

                return wmi.GetPropertyValue("SerialNumber").ToString();


            }
        }
        catch (COMException ce)
        {
            if ((uint)ce.ErrorCode == 0x800706BA)
            {
                return "Serial Number : Null";
            }
        }

        return "Serial Number : Null";


    }
```